# Elm: Use `Address String Action`

Tags: elm

The canonical example for getting the value from an [input](http://elm-lang.org/examples/field) is:

```
view : Address String -> String -> Html
view address string =
  div []
    [ input
        [ placeholder "Text to reverse"
        , value string
        , on "input" targetValue (Signal.message address)
        , myStyle
        ]
        []
    , div [ myStyle ] [ text (String.reverse string) ]
    ]
```

I get this.  But I want my address to be of type `Address String Action` (where Action is some other type I define). To my understanding, this would mean the address expects a `String` followed by a `Action` type as it's "arguments" (I think of `Address` as a function, but that might not be correct).

Is it possible to use an address type of `Address String Action`, and then use it with an input in a similar way?  Or am I allowed to do `Address String Action` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/field) you link to is probably a bit too simplistic in that both the Action and Model are a string. You will seldom run into that.

I've tweaked the example with something that is more canonical to elm in its current form:

```elm
main =
  StartApp.start { model = { text = "" }, view = view, update = update }

type Action
  = SetText String

type alias Model =
  { text : String }

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    SetText text ->
      { model | text = text }

view : Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  div []
    [ input
        [ placeholder "Text to reverse"
        , value model.text
        , on "input" targetValue (Signal.message address << SetText)
        , myStyle
        ]
        []
    , div [ myStyle ] [ text (String.reverse model.text) ]
    ]
```

Notice how the `Action` type is a union type listing all the different ways you can interact with the page. In this example, the only thing you can do is to set the text.

The signature of `view` is now more explicit. The first argument is the address of a mailbox that deals in type `Action`, and the second argument contains the current state of the model.

```elm
view : Address Action -> Model -> Html
```

There is no need to go down a path of trying something like `Address String Action` since now `Action` encapsulates the setting of the text.